# Parabolic fall-off growth rate in polar coordinate PDE by separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following PDE with parabolic fall-off growth rate in polar coordinates.$$\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}=\alpha_0\left(1-\frac{r^2}{R^2}\right)n+D\frac 1r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial n}{\partial r}\right)$$where $0<r<\infty$.

So far what I have done:

Let $n(r,t) = e^{\alpha_{0}t}u(r,t)$ and substitute into the PDE,

$$\alpha_{0}e^{\alpha_{0}t}u + e^{\alpha_{0}t}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \alpha_{0}\left( 1 - \frac{r^{2}}{R^{2}} \right)e^{\alpha_{0}t}u + D\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left( re^{\alpha_{0}t}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \right)$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = - \alpha_{0}\left( \frac{r}{R} \right)^{2}u + D\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left( r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \right)$$

Let $u(r,t) = S(r)T(t)$ and substitute into the above equation,

$$S(r)T^{'}(t) = - \alpha_{0}\left( \frac{r}{R} \right)^{2}S(r)T(t) + D\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left( rS^{'}(r)T(t) \right)$$

$$S(r)T^{'}(t) = - \alpha_{0}\left( \frac{r}{R} \right)^{2}S(r)T(t) + DT(t)\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left( rS^{'}(r) \right)$$

$$\frac{1}{D}\frac{T^{'}(t)}{T(t)} = - \frac{\alpha_{0}}{D}\left( \frac{r}{R} \right)^{2} + \frac{1}{rS(r)}\frac{d}{dr}\left( rS^{'}(r) \right)$$

Assume that

$$- \lambda = \frac{1}{D}\frac{T^{'}(t)}{T(t)} = - \frac{\alpha_{0}}{D}\left( \frac{r}{R} \right)^{2} + \frac{1}{rS(r)}\frac{d}{dr}\left( r\frac{dS}{dr} \right)$$

Then

$$T^{'} = - \lambda DT$$

$$\frac{d}{dr}\left( r\frac{dS}{dr} \right) + \left( \lambda - \frac{\alpha_{0}}{D}\left( \frac{r}{R} \right)^{2} \right)rS = 0$$

The second equation maybe re-written as

$$r\frac{d^{2}S}{dr^{2}} + \frac{dS}{dr} + \left( \lambda - \frac{\alpha_{0}}{D}\left( \frac{r}{R} \right)^{2} \right)rS = 0$$
Does the above ODE have known solutions?

Note I am reading a book "elements of mathematical ecology". This question comes from [chapter16](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/elements-of-mathematical-ecology/spatial-steady-states-linear-problems/18654895AE2BA96745BE5D58C05165D5). In this chapter, the author first demonstrated how to solve the heat equation with an exponential growth term and a radially symmetric diffusion term by separation of variables to reduce it to a Bessel function. Then the author shows another example where there is 1D quadratic fall-off growth rate with constant diffusion term, which is solved by separation of variable to reduce to Schrödinger equation. The last example is very similar to this question where the diffusion term is modified to a 2D radially symmetric term. I don't know whether I am in the right direction to approach this question anyway. If you don't have access to the book let me know.

Comment: @MatthewCassell I made some comments in the question. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differential equation
$$
r\frac{d^{2}S}{dr^{2}} + \frac{dS}{dr} + \left( \lambda - \frac{\alpha_{0}}{D}\left( \frac{r}{R} \right)^{2} \right)rS = 0 \tag{1}
$$
can be reduced to *Laguerre's differential equation*$^{(*)}$. To show how, let's first simplify the notation by defining the parameters
$$
b=\left(\frac{\alpha_0}{DR^2}\right)^{1/2}, \qquad \mu=\frac{\lambda}{4b}, \tag{2}
$$
so that $(1)$ can be rewritten as
$$
r\frac{d^{2}S}{dr^{2}} + \frac{dS}{dr} + \left( 4b\mu - b^2r^2 \right)rS = 0. \tag{3}
$$
Next, if we change the independent variable $r$ to $x=br^2$, equation $(3)$ is transformed to
$$
x\frac{d^{2}S}{dx^{2}} + \frac{dS}{dx} + \left( \mu - \frac{x}{4} \right)S = 0. \tag{4}
$$
Finally, let $S(x)=e^{-x/2}U(x)$; substituting this into equation $(4)$ gives
$$
x\frac{d^2U}{dx^2}+(1-x)\frac{dU}{dx}+\left(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\right)U=0. \tag{5}
$$
This equation has nonsingular solutions only if $\mu-\frac{1}{2}$ is a nonnegative integer.

---

$^{(*)}$https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials